# Inflating Google Maps v2 fragment causes ClassNotFoundException / Application LBS has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, classnotfoundexception, android-maps-v2

I'm fairly new to Android Dev. Just trying to get a simple map to appear using Google Android Map API v2. I'm not trying to do anything special here...I would have thought that I'd have this working in 30 minutes or less...embarrassingly and frustratingly two days later I'm still stuck. Arg! I've spent a lot of time trying different things, reading documentation, and even tried to drop back to v1 Map API...with no success.

The app crashes immediately on my real phone with the following message: "Application LBS has stopped unexpectedly".

I've looked at multiple posting and still haven't been able to find my problem so I'm hoping someone can spot the problem.

I created a key per [Google's instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro) and think I successfully completed the other steps outlined on this page.

I'm running the app on my phone which is running Android v2.2.1. It is my understanding that the v2 API will not run on an emulator...you must use a real device. Hopefully Google will rectify that issue at some point in the near future.

Here is the LogCat...it appears to be choking on the inflating the Fragment.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity \
       ComponentInfo{com.example.lbs/com.example.lbs.MainActivity}: \
       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: \
       Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: \
       Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:200)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
    at com.example.lbs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    ... 11 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader 
       dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:\
       /data/app/com.example.lbs-2.apk]
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
    ... 19 more
```

Here is the MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.lbs;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }
}
```

Here is the manifest. Note there are some extra's in here that aren't needed..I've been trying all sorts of stuff to try to get this simple app to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lbs"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.lbs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.lbs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission `enter code here`android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.lbs.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCC-v65frsK6-VZjHrEMqr0wyjorLuDXXX
            " />
</application>
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
</manifest>
```

Here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after spending several days trying to get this work I finally just gave up this afternoon and pretty much started over again...I finally just got this work on my Android v2.2.1 phone by following this tutorial (http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/12/google-rolls-out-android-maps-api-v2/).

Google maps is a great utility but it should NOT be this difficult to use...just the process of getting a API key is onerous.

Unlike the Google material this tutorial was very clear, concise and accurate. It literally took me 30 minutes to get it to work after I consulted this tutorial. That was after 2-3 days trying to figure it out with Google materials.  Google doc people should take a look at this tutorial and emulate it. Wow...how refreshing it was. Don't know if their other Android tutorials are as clear but if so it will be my first stop for all Android documentation.

Comment: I think Google has done a great job in documentating the process on the google maps developer site. Getting an API key by providing an application package and a keytool fingerprint isn't that onerous.

Comment: I think the number of questions/problems regarding maps/license issues speaks for itself.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment was not introduced until Android 3.0. However, you can get support for it in earlier versions using the support library. Please see more information [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html).

Comment: Thanks unless I'm missing something I don't think that is the problem. I already have the android-support-v4.jar file installed in the apps (LBS)Lib folder. Even so just to make sure I added the Fragment import statements to the MainActivity suggested in the link. Result = same exact failure.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainActivity` should extend `FragmentActivity` not Activity

If you are using the support library you should use the

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```